# SQL Server 2008 query not executing properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have to run this query on my SQL Server 2008.

I need to join the 2 tables (`Gasper_object` and `Ticket`) and get the results where `Gasper_object.id` is also shown.

```
SELECT 
    TICKET.ACTION_CODE_KEY,
    TICKET.OBJECT_KEY,
    GASPER_OBJECT.ID, 
    CASE
        WHEN ACTION_CODE_KEY IN (4,8) THEN 'OUT OF SERVICE'
        WHEN ACTION_CODE_KEY IS NULL THEN 'IN SERVICE'
        ELSE 'FAULTY SERVICE' 
    END "STATUS"
FROM 
    TICKET
INNER JOIN 
    GASPER_OBJECT ON ticket.OBJECT_KEY = GASPER_OBJECT.OBJECT_KEY 
GROUP BY 
    ticket.object_key, GASPER_OBJECT.ID;
```

What should I do ?

**UPDATE**

This is what I received as a task to complete

- IF THE ACTION_CODE IS 4 OR 8, THE COLOUMN NAME SHOULD BE OUT OF SERVICE

  - OTHERWISE IT SHOULD BE FAULTY SERVICE
  - IF THE OBJECT HAS NO TICKET AT ALL THEN IT'S IN SERVICE
  - GASPER_OBJECT.ID, STATUS SHOULD BE THE OUTPUT COLUMNS AFTER QUERYING
  - IF THE OBJECT HAS MORE THAN ONE TICKET WHICH APPLIES TO THE CRITERIA, USE DISTINCT

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.  Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why is that I can't see what's wrong with the query..? Could you please point out?

Comment: Syntax is ok, but you are having group by inconsistency. The general GROUP BY rule is:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: The `ACTION_CODE_KEY  ` is not in aggrigate or in group by

Comment: I see "Status" being in the double quotes.

Comment: Just add rest of the columns to the group by and I think it will work.

Comment: Thank you @SorrelVesper , i added the remaining columns and it worked :)

Comment: I will add this as the answer then, so that you can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add rest of the columns to the group by.

```
SELECT 
    TICKET.ACTION_CODE_KEY,
    TICKET.OBJECT_KEY,
    GASPER_OBJECT.ID, 
    CASE
        WHEN ACTION_CODE_KEY IN (4,8) THEN 'OUT OF SERVICE'
        WHEN ACTION_CODE_KEY IS NULL THEN 'IN SERVICE'
        ELSE 'FAULTY SERVICE' 
    END "STATUS"
FROM 
    TICKET
INNER JOIN 
    GASPER_OBJECT ON ticket.OBJECT_KEY = GASPER_OBJECT.OBJECT_KEY 
GROUP BY 
    TICKET.ACTION_CODE_KEY, ticket.object_key, GASPER_OBJECT.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks again :)

 it would be helpful if you can tell how to use DISTINCT for the proper result

Comment: What seems to be the problem? The data is repeated?

Comment: gasper_object.id and ticket.object_key are repeated sir

Answer (score 0):

In an aggregation query, all the columns not in the `group by` need to be arguments to aggregation functions.  Here is an example of query that should at least run:

```
SELECT t.object_key, o.ID,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(ACTION_CODE_KEY)  IN (4, 8) THEN 'OUT OF SERVICE'
             WHEN MAX(ACTION_CODE_KEY) IS NULL THEN 'IN SERVICE'
             ELSE 'FAULTY SERVICE' 
        END) as STATUS
FROM TICKET t inner join
     GASPER_OBJECT o
     on t.OBJECT_KEY = o.OBJECT_KEY 
group by t.object_key, o.ID;
```

Your question doesn't explain what you want to do, so this may or may not produce the results you expect.